# How do I loop through a GraphTraversal object in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, gremlin

In the Gremlin console I can use valueMap() to print all properties of vertexes resulting in multiple lines of output. But how can I iterate over them in Node.js?

Gremlin queries:

```
gremlin> g.V().toList()
==>v[64]
==>v[68]
gremlin> g.V().valueMap(true)
==>{id=64, name=[Brick 1], part_number=[000001], uuid=[cb5fa832-ef75-44e7-a2b6-0a39be14d86c]}
==>{id=68, name=[Brick 2], part_number=[000001], uuid=[19c69323-7844-4260-b317-0bbec67d74d3]}
```

Node.js code:

```
import {driver, structure} from 'gremlin';
import DriverRemoteConnection = driver.DriverRemoteConnection;
import Graph = structure.Graph;

const g = new Graph().traversal().withRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin'));

console.log(g.V().toList());    <= working
```

However, using valueMap() instead of toList() will return a GraphTraversal object which I cannot handle. How do I get the actual results?

```
GraphTraversal {
  graph: Graph {},
  traversalStrategies: TraversalStrategies { strategies: [ [RemoteStrategy] ] },
  bytecode:
   Bytecode {
     sourceInstructions: [],
     stepInstructions: [ [Array], [Array] ] },
  traversers: null,
...
```

I am using the npm package "gremlin": "^3.4.1"

Thanks, Amadeus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toList()` is just a terminating step. `valueMap()` is just another graph traversal step. You need a terminator to your graph traversal so that Gremlin knows how to iterate the result. Just add `toList()` after `valueMap()`.

```
g.V().valueMap().toList()
```